# responsive input field width (or other elements)

Tags: css

I have an input text field which is inside a div, I want to make it equal to the width of that div. I try to set the width same as the div by css, but when I resized the windows, the input field defected..

Comment: Can you show your html and css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have paddings, use http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

```
input{ 
  width:100%;
  padding: 5px;
  border:1px solid black;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
  box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
input{
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing:border-box
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always set its width to `100%`.

Answer (score 0):

give input text width as 100%

```
 <input type="text" style="width: 100%"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set property of Div with

```
  overflow:hidden
```

and set textbox with

```
width:100%
```

to avoid this issue. see this fiddle if helps http://jsfiddle.net/Rj8aj/

Answer (score 0):

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/dKtwm/) with css

**`css`**

```
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    }
body {
    font:normal 12px/18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#000;
    padding:20px;
    background-color:#F2F2F2;
    }
ul, li, ol {
    list-style-type:none;
    }

.wrapper {
    width:96%;
    padding:2%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#3D3A40;
}
.greenBox {
    background-color:#006600;
    padding:50px;
    }
.spacer {
    clear:both;
    font-size:0;
    line-height:0;
    height:0;
    }
p {
    padding-bottom:18px;
    }
input {
    height:26px;
    border: none;
    color:#fff;
    border:#83bbd9 1px solid;
    width:100%;
    font:normal 12px/26px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="greenBox">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input name="" type="text" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```